# VS 2012 solution and projects - incompatible with VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, compatibility

I was under the assumption the solutions and / or C# projects created in VS 2012 could also be opened in VS 2010 (with SP1 applied).

But I wasn't able to do so - VS 2010 didn't want to load the solution file, and after I manually "tweaked" it, now it complains about the `*.csproj` project file being *incompatible* with this current version of VS 2010 .....

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Visual Studio 2012 csproj backward compatible with 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902865/is-visual-studio-2012-csproj-backward-compatible-with-2010)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create a solution with visual studio 2012 on the top of your solution-file there are the following two lines:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
```

You can Replace the Version 12 to 11. And than the solution should work in Visual Studio 2010.  I'm not sure if the visual studio 2010 can handle project-files which have target .net-framework 4.5

Comment: That's what I tried - I can now open the **solution** - but the project file is still considered "incompatible" ....

Comment: Try to open the solution again in visual studio 2012 and set the target framework of each project to .net 4.0.

Comment: Yup - setting the target framework to `4.0` solved that problem - thanks!

Comment: This works the first time but as soon as I compile again in VS2012, the solution file gets checked out and the version changes back to 12 again.

Comment: My coworker helped me create a copy named projectVS2010.sln in addition to the existing project.sln (still in 2012). Maybe that's a good solution... or do bad things happen when having both of those side by side? (Fortunately, no one's actively working on this using the 2012 one right now.)

Answer (score 8):

You can fix it by,

1- Change `12.00` to `11.00`

2- open `*.csproj` file by text editor and change this line

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Project will open after restart of VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

Removing:

```
<AppContainerApplication>true</AppContainerApplication>
```

Under the tag:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
```

Solved it for me. Though it is funny, on another PC (Win10 instead of 7) it worked including this line.