# Open MahApps.Metro-master Projects in VS2010 (.net4.0)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mahapps.metro

I am new to WPF & Planning to design a wpf project with [MahApps Metro Master](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/).

I download a sample Source from this [Link](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro).
I am using VS2010, this project is not opening in VS2010. I think its developed by VS2012. 
Is it possible to open this file in VS2010. (Or) Is there any link for download a `MahApps Metro` sample project for VS2010.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

See these answers for information on compatibility between VS2012 and VS2010:

1. [Converting VS2012 Solution to VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143383/converting-vs2012-solution-to-vs2010)
2. [Is Visual Studio 2012 csproj backward compatible with 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902865/is-visual-studio-2012-csproj-backward-compatible-with-2010)

In terms of using the MahApps .dlls in you own project this should not be a problem. Just include the appropriate references in your project and away you go.

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. This `MahApps` controls are working fine in my project. I want see the `xaml` files which is contains in `<ResourceDictionary>`..

Comment: Well, either convert using the links I provided or open the XAML files individually with VS2010 or another editor of your choice.